# Colaboradores para Tradução do Site 'How To Ask Questions The Smart Way'

Tags: novo-recurso

Estamos dispostos a traduzir [o excelente "How To Ask Questions The Smart Way"](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), já que o link da tradução para o português está quebrado.

Para isso, precisamos de alguns voluntários. Basicamente farei uma tradução bruta do documento usando uma ferramenta e depois teremos que refinar para que fique numa boa qualidade.

Responda esta pergunta se você está interessado em colaborar. Tendo pelo menos cinco pessoas, avisaremos os autores de nossa intenção e definiremos como distribuir o trabalho.

Lembrando que isso é um esforço voluntário.

---

#### Política de tradução [conforme o site do autor](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/copying.html):

> - Se quiser traduzir, vá em frente, eu autorizo e incluirei um link para ela quando você me mandar o URL.
> - Você mantém e hospeda a tradução, não eu. Eu não mantenho traduções no meu site porque quando faço isso elas nunca são atualizadas.
> - Nem me pergunte se eu conheço traduções para alguma linguagem específica. Se eu conhecer, ela estará listada juntos com os outros
>   links para traduções no documento original.
> - É obrigatório incluir um link bem visível para o original.
> - É obrigatório incluir um timestamp visível na tradução, assim os leitores poderão verificar se ela está defasada em relação ao
>   original, que está sempre em mutação.

Comment: É uma ótima proposta, o texto lá é muito bem feito. Tenho interesse em ajudar.

Comment: http://www.fabrica10.com.br/projetos/comofazerperguntasinteligentes.html esse texto?

Comment: Mesmo não conseguindo abrir o link do post nem do comentário acima, eu interesso em ajudar no que for possível. (3g do interior não é lá grandes coisas)

Comment: Tenho interesse também se precisar.

Comment: @rray Podemos começar deste link que você mandou e ir melhorando ele pra ficar próximo do original. Já notei que algumas partes estão faltando.

Comment: *Count me in.* Como sugestão de ferramenta opensource para tradução colaborativa: http://zanata.org/

Comment: Com isto temos cinco pessoas: eu, OnoSendai, Arthur de Andrade, rray e emanuelsn, fora o Gabe que já se manifestou a favor. Já criei minha conta no Zanata.

Comment: Também posso ajudar.

Comment: Tb posso dar ajudar

Comment: Já que temos muita gente pra traduzir, posso revisar o texto.

Comment: Eu posso participar da revisão ou tradução.

Comment: A tradução original parece estar aqui: http://www.contraditorium.com/2006/02/15/como-fazer-perguntas-inteligentes/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Etapa Atual

O autor foi contatado. Estamos prontos para começar.

Iniciei um documento no Google Drive porque o Zanata não é um editor, e sim, um repositório de documentos. [O link para o documento inicial está aqui](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MR6qR_pgewJBZ8HV8vFj4GTFg3p0jzy5omAYA-vZH9M/edit?usp=sharing). Todo mundo pode editar.

---

Há também [uma tradução oficial aqui](http://www.contraditorium.com/2006/02/15/como-fazer-perguntas-inteligentes/).

Comment: Aqui aparece-me tudo em português...

Comment: Sim, agora temos que deixar o texto com qualidade. Só passei uma tradução automática e estou formatando parágrafos.

Comment: Olha só, não sabia que o Cardoso já tinha traduzido.

Answer (score 3):

Recebemos a resposta ontem.
Podemos seguir em frente desde que respeitados [os seguintes termos](http://www.catb.org/esr/copying.html):

> Parte jurídica enfadonha mas necessária: Eric S. Raymond detem o direito autoral sobre todo o conteúdo deste site. Todos os direitos reservados sob a lei de direito autoral dos EUA e a Convenção de Berna (onde cabível), exceto nos casos listados abaixo.
>   Muitas pessoas me perguntam se podem criar links para o meu site, replicá-lo, traduzir o conteúdo, etc. Essas são minhas normas:
>
> - Você pode criar links para qualquer parte do site.
> - Você pode replicar qualquer parte do site.
> - Você não pode criar ou distribuir cópias estáticas (impressa ou online) sem meu consentimento expresso.
>
> Normalmente, gosto que muitas pessoas tenham acesso ao meu conteúdo, e se você quiser ajudar neste sentido, não vejo problema algum. Mas não gosto quando versões antigas e abandonadas do que escrevo espalhadas por outros sites. Essas regras são uma forma de garantir que quando alguém vir meu nome em um documento, o material esteja na sua versão mais atual.
>   Dessa forma, qualquer pedido que envolva a alteração do conteúdo original, para um público em particular, será negado. Não adianta perguntar, a resposta é não. O melhor a fazer é escrever seu próprio texto, usando o meu como referência, e fornecer um link para a versão original ou traduzida.
>
> Traduções são um caso especial, sob estas regras:
>
> - Qualquer tradução é permitida. Me envie o link e disponibilizarei no meu site.
> - *Você* deve hospedar, e manter, sua própria tradução. Não gosto de mantê-las no meu site porque elas acabam ficando defasadas.
> - Se eu souber de alguma tradução para uma determinada língua, o link estará disponível no meu site. Se o link não existir, eu não sei de nenhuma tradução, não precisa perguntar.
> - Você deve exibir o link para o documento original deve ser claramente exibido.
> - Você deve manter um histórico datado de atualizações no seu documento, para que os leitores possam saber se ele se encontra atualizado e corresponde fielmente ao original.

Essa é uma tradução informal dos termos no site do ESR, já que "advogado" é uma das várias coisas que eu não sou.

Ele se mostrou disposto a substituir as traduções pt-br e pt-pt no site e não se mostrou preocupado com a maneira como vamos traduzir e hospedar, então estamos livres para manter o documento da maneira que quisermos.

Comment: Er, eu já tinha traduzido uma parte disso na própria pergunta...

Comment: @bfavaretto A aba tava aberta aqui desde ontem. Não atualizei antes de responder

Comment: Sem problemas. Mas eu não podia perder a chance de cutucar ;)